# Printf, SIGABRT и USIGNED LONG LONG

Tags: c, printf

На Windows все работает, но чекер на линуксе, который почему-то начал ругаться, хотя никакого WinAPI не использовал

Собственно, код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/*  НАСТРОЙКИ */
bool debugging = false; //Отладка

void ZFunc(char **gr_string, unsigned long long int gr_str_len, unsigned long long int **zf){
    unsigned long long int left, right, i;

    for (i = 0; i < gr_str_len; i++) {
        (*zf)[i] = 0;
    }
    left = right = 0;


    for (i = 1; i < gr_str_len; ++i) {

        if (i <= right) {
           (*zf)[i]=fmin((right-i+1), (*zf)[i-1]);
        }



       (*zf)[i+1] = fmax(0, fmin(right-1, (*zf)[i-left+1]));


       while ( ((i+(*zf)[i]) < gr_str_len) && ( (*gr_string)[(*zf)[i]] == (*gr_string)[i+(*zf)[i]] ) ){

           ++(*zf)[i];

       }

       if ((i+(*zf)[i]-1)>right) {
           left = i;
           right = i + (*zf)[i]-1;
       }

    }


}



int ZSerch(char **subtext, unsigned long long int subtext_length, char **maintext, unsigned long long int maintext_length, unsigned long long int stringnum){
  unsigned long long int *zf;
  unsigned long long int i, gr_str_len;
  char *gr_string;
  unsigned long long int space_count, space_stop;
  bool kek = true;



  //Создание Огроменной строки

  gr_str_len = subtext_length+maintext_length+2;
  gr_string = (char*)malloc((gr_str_len)*sizeof(char));


  for (i = 0; i < subtext_length; i++) {
    gr_string[i] = (*subtext)[i];
  }

  gr_string[i] = '$';

  for (i = 0; i <= maintext_length; i++) {
    gr_string[i+subtext_length+1] = (*maintext)[i];
  }

  free(*maintext);

  //Подготовка численного массива
  zf =  (unsigned long long int*)malloc((gr_str_len)*sizeof(unsigned long long int));


  //  Z - функция
  ZFunc(&gr_string, gr_str_len, &zf);


   // Вывод
  if (debugging == true) {
      printf("\n----------\n");
      for (i = 0; i <= gr_str_len; i++) {
         printf("%llu", zf[i]);
      }
      printf("\n----------\n");
  }


  // Подготовка и вывод данных

  space_count = 0;
   space_stop = subtext_length;

  for (i = subtext_length; i < gr_str_len-1; i++) {
    if (zf[i] == subtext_length) {

      while (space_stop < i){
        if (gr_string[space_stop] < '0') {
          space_count++;
          kek = true;
        } else {
          kek = false;
        }

        space_stop++;
      }

      if ((kek == true) && (i+subtext_length <= gr_str_len-1) && (gr_string[i+subtext_length] < '0')) {

         printf("%llu", stringnum);
         printf(", ");
         printf("%llu", (space_count-1));
         printf("\n");
         kek = false;
      }
    }
  }

  free(zf);
  return 0;
}



int main(){

    unsigned long long int count_abd  = 0; //Количество символов в строке абзадца
    unsigned short count_free = 1;         //Количество свободы  в строке абзадца
    char *patt;   // Подстрока, которую ищем

    unsigned long long int count_ssk  = 0; //Количество символов в строке абзадца
    unsigned short     count_free_ssk = 5;         //Количество свободы  в строке абзадца
    char *string_s; // Подстрока, которую ищем


    unsigned long long int string_count  = 0;  //Сколько строк обработали (нужно для вывода)

    bool exitkey = false;

    // Забиваем образец

    patt = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

    if ((scanf("%c", &(patt[count_abd]))) > 0){

       patt[count_abd] = tolower(patt[count_abd]);

       count_free--;
       count_abd++;

       while (patt[count_abd-1] != '\n'){

           if (count_free == 0) {
             patt = (char*)realloc(patt, ((count_abd+16)*(sizeof(char))));
             count_free=count_free+16;
           }


           patt[count_abd] = tolower(getchar());

           count_free--;
           count_abd++;

       }

       count_free++;
       count_abd--;
       patt[count_abd] = 0;

       // Получаем строку, в которой ищем
       string_s = (char*)malloc(5*sizeof(char));
       count_ssk++;
       count_free_ssk--;


       while ((scanf("%c", &string_s[count_ssk-1]) > 0) && (exitkey == false)){

          if ((string_s[count_ssk-1] != '#')||(string_s[count_ssk-1] != '$')||(string_s[count_ssk-1] != '@')) {


            string_count++;


            string_s[count_ssk+1]=  tolower(string_s[count_ssk-1]);
            string_s[count_ssk-1] = '@';
            string_s[count_ssk] = ' ';
            count_ssk=count_ssk+2;



            while (string_s[count_ssk-1] != '\n'){

              if (count_free_ssk >= 3 ) {
                   string_s = (char*)realloc(string_s, ((count_ssk*1.5)+5)*(sizeof(char)));
                   count_free_ssk=((count_ssk*0.5)+5);
              }

                  string_s[count_ssk] = tolower(getchar());
                  count_free_ssk--;
                  count_ssk++;
            }

            count_free_ssk++;
            count_ssk--;
            string_s[count_ssk] = 0;


            //  Поиск подстроки в строке  и там же вывод
            ZSerch(&patt, count_abd, &string_s, count_ssk, string_count);

            // Обнуление
            count_ssk = 1;
            count_free_ssk = 0;
            string_s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

          }  else exitkey = true;


       }









    }

    free(patt);
    free(string_s);




    return 0;
}
```

При отладке, выяснил, что *SIGABRT* происходит на:

> printf("%llu", stringnum);

Но почему это происходит - хз.

Надеюсь, более опытные специалисты смогут мне помочь....

Спасибо!

P.S. Пример ввода

```
a
a b
```

Comment: Может, ему нужен другой спецификатор для `unsigned long long`?

Comment: @Harry - хз, впервые с таким столкнулся;
Отладчик на prinf чтоб вылетал

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG Причину найти легко, если выкидывать из программы все, что не меняет ситуацию с ошибкой. За вас это вряд ли кто будет делать, если ошибка сразу же не бросится в глаза

Comment: @VladfromMoscow я же указал место ошибки и наименование ошибки... Т.е. я это уже проделал... Я не понимаю - "Но почему это происходит - хз."!!! Читайте внимательней, пожалуйста

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG Это может никакого отношения к проблеме не иметь. Причиной ошибке может быть, например, выход за пределы массива и, как следствие, неопределенное поведение программы. Разбираться в этом плохом коде предоставьте автору этого кода.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow ошибка происходит на printfе - если его убрать - все фурычит идеально

Comment: @VladfromMoscow я и есть автор кода

Comment: @VladfromMoscow А вот нюансы - я и прошу помочь найти - через 2 часа сдавать

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG Вот и отлаживайте свой собственный код.

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG Лично я вообще не понимаю, почему параметр zf в функции ZFunc является указателем на указатель.

Comment: Для экономии памяти

Comment: Каким образом использование указателя на указатель вместо обычного указателя экономит память - не ясно. Также: странная манера выносить объявления переменных в начало функции сильно затрудняет чтение кода.

Comment: "При отладке, выяснил, что SIGABRT происходит на:..." На каких входных данных??? Сколько можно дылдонить одно и то же: почему в вопорсе не приведен вход, на котором происходит падение???

Comment: @AnT Сорри, на любом вводе из 2х непустых строк

Comment: Например: a и a b a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по тому, как написана ваша функция `ZFunc`

```
for (i = 1; i < (*gr_string)[0]; i++) {
```

она ожидает, что в элементе `(*gr_string)[0]` ей будет передано какое-то "особое" значение. Длина строки, по-видимому.

Но когда вы готовите строку `gr_string` в `ZSerch`, никакого особого значения в `gr_string[0]` вы не записываете. `gr_string[0]` - это просто первый символ искомой строки.

Что это за путаница и почему вы сами этого не в состоянии увидеть - надо спрашивать у вас.

Comment: Мдя... Была там ошибочка, но не она вызывала проблему.

Comment: обновил код, с учетом ваших и нетолько замечаний

Comment: Но проблема наблюдается до сих пор